# Fazer upload para Drive

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, google-drive-api

Pessoal tenho o seguinte código, que abre a tela de consentimento do google, onde é feita a autorização do usuário e gerado um token de autenticação:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
    AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

    if (result.Credential != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = result.Credential.UserId;
        DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
            ApplicationName = "DriveApi",
        });
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
    }
}
```

Na verdade estou travado nesta parte:

```
DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "DriveApi",
            });
```

Só que acontece que eu preciso chamar esta parte dentro de um método static, porque depois que faço a autenticação somente o DriveService sera necessário, só que ao fazer esta parte em um metodo static o result.Credential não existe, existe apenas o result.  E preciso da Credential para que tudo funcione corretamente.

Só que agora preciso fazer o upload do arquivo, só que não achei nada na internet sobre como fazer isso que seja de maneira clara, alguém já trabalhou com isso e poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Você quer fazer esse upload de um aquivo já existente, quer que o usuário faça o upload do arquivo, o que exatamente você deseja?

Comment: Então é um arquivo já existente na maquina, que sera feito upload para o drive do usuário.

Comment: Quer fazer o upload para uma conta do usuário ou para uma conta do Google Drive drive pré definida?

Comment: Upload para conta do usuário

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos por partes.

Primeiro, [o exemplo de OAuth em Asp.NET MVC você pode ver aqui](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc), mas irei transcrever a forma de utilização aqui.

Instale o pacote [Google APIs Auth MVC Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.MVC/), com o seguinte comando no  Package Manager Console:

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc

Feito isso, primeiro teremos que criar `AppFlowMetadata`.

> FlowMetadata É uma classe abstrata que contém sua própria lógica para recuperar o identificador de usuário eo que IAuthorizationCodeFlow você está usando.

O código seria isso:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4
{
    public class AppFlowMetadata : FlowMetadata
    {
        private static readonly IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
                {
                    ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
                    {
                        ClientId = "PUT_CLIENT_ID_HERE",
                        ClientSecret = "PUT_CLIENT_SECRET_HERE"
                    },
                    Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                    DataStore = new FileDataStore("Drive.Api.Auth.Store")
                });

        public override string GetUserId(Controller controller)
        {
            // In this sample we use the session to store the user identifiers.
            // That's not the best practice, because you should have a logic to identify
            // a user. You might want to use "OpenID Connect".
            // You can read more about the protocol in the following link:
            // https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.
            var user = controller.Session["user"];
            if (user == null)
            {
                user = Guid.NewGuid();
                controller.Session["user"] = user;
            }
            return user.ToString();

        }

        public override IAuthorizationCodeFlow Flow
        {
            get { return flow; }
        }
    }
}
```

Agora, vamos implementar o nosso `AuthCallbackController`, que será a URL de retorno da Google.

```
using Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4;

namespace Google.Apis.Sample.MVC4.Controllers
{
    public class AuthCallbackController : Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.Controllers.AuthCallbackController
    {
        protected override Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Mvc.FlowMetadata FlowData
        {
            get { return new AppFlowMetadata(); }
        }
    }
}
```

> OBS.: Não se esqueça de adicionar essa URL de retorno no Console de seu aplicativo na Google.

Feito isso, iremos para a `HomeController`, onde faremos o upload do arquivo, que [você pode ver o exemplo da Google aqui.](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(cancellationToken);

        if (result.Credential != null)
        {
            var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
                ApplicationName = "ASP.NET MVC Sample"
            });

            // YOUR CODE SHOULD BE HERE..
            // SAMPLE CODE:
            var list = await service.Files.List().ExecuteAsync();
            ViewBag.Message = "FILE COUNT IS: " + list.Files.Count();

            var fileMetadata = new File()
            {
                Name = "photo.jpg"
            };
            FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\CAMINHO_DA_IMAGEM_AQUI",
                                    System.IO.FileMode.Open))
            {
                request = service.Files.Create(
                    fileMetadata, stream, "image/png");
                request.Fields = "id";
                request.Upload();
            }
            var file = request.ResponseBody;


            return View();
        }
        else
        {

            var pause = true;
            return new RedirectResult(result.RedirectUri);
        }
    }
}
```

Note que alterei apenas para retornar uma `ActionResult`, mas a parte do upload continua a mesma.

Note que neste exemplo, será criado um arquivo chamado `photo.jpg` no Google Drive do usuário.

Comment: Amigo só estou tendo um problema, que para cada sessão esta sendo gerado um token diferente, só que para isso é preciso fazer esse processo de autenticação novamente, porém não é necessário aceitar nada se eu já aceitei uma vez, é preciso abrir a tela para executar o "GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow" para gerar outro token, e a partir dai fazer o upload, sabe oque poderia estar acontecendo?